# radio button check and uncheck other radio buttons the web form is connected with a database created using ms access

Tags: asp.net

i have two radio buttons  in an web application named male and female  and used the following code to check a button and uncheck other one  but it isnt working when i m ruunning it both  are selected .what to do?

```
    protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            RadioButton2.Checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            RadioButton2.Checked = true;


        }


    }

    protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            RadioButton1.Checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            RadioButton2.Checked = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a [RadioButtonList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx) for this.  It will give you radio buttons that belong to the same group and automatically have the behavior that the other buttons in the group are unchecked when a different button in the group is checked.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening is when you are doing `RadioButton2.Checked =false` in 
`protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` you are triggering  `protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` and therfor checking both. Your `radio buttons` need to be `grouped` so that they are `1 item` and you shouldn't need any code behind to make them work.